# Using ng-if as a switch inside ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, dom, laravel-4, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-if

I am working on Angular app. I tried to use ng-if and switch inside **ng-repeat** but didn't succeed. I have data like:

```
   **[{"_id":"52fb84fac6b93c152d8b4569",
       "post_id":"52fb84fac6b93c152d8b4567",
       "user_id":"52df9ab5c6b93c8e2a8b4567",
       "type":"hoot",},  
      {"_id":"52fb798cc6b93c74298b4568",
       "post_id":"52fb798cc6b93c74298b4567",
       "user_id":"52df9ab5c6b93c8e2a8b4567",
       "type":"story",},        
      {"_id":"52fb7977c6b93c5c2c8b456b",
       "post_id":"52fb7977c6b93c5c2c8b456a",
       "user_id":"52df9ab5c6b93c8e2a8b4567",
       "type":"article",},**
```

$scope.comments = data mentioned above
and my Html like :

```
   <div ng-repeat = "data in comments">
      <div ng-if="hoot == data.type">
          //differnt template with hoot data
       </div>
      <div ng-if="story == data.type">
          //differnt template with story data
       </div>
       <div ng-if="article == data.type">
          //differnt template with article data
       </div> 
   </div>
```

How can I achieve this thing in Angular?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Try to surround `strings` (`hoot`, `story`, `article`) with quotes `'`:

```
<div ng-repeat = "data in comments">
    <div ng-if="data.type == 'hoot' ">
        //different template with hoot data
    </div>
    <div ng-if="data.type == 'story' ">
        //different template with story data
    </div>
    <div ng-if="data.type == 'article' ">
        //different template with article data
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Just to point out the difference (since I didn't see it immediately): the answer is to surround the Strings with quotes. Using them as direct literals won't work.

Comment: Is this above solution got worked.... ???  i tried the same but it doesn't get worked :( please help how to work with ng-if to check with literals

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. It still shows even with `ng-if='false'` and `ng-show='false'`

Answer (score 85):

This one is noteworthy as well

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts" ng-if="post.type=='article'">
  <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: `ng-if` in `ng-repeat` is Helpful

Comment: This doesn't work at least for angular 1.2: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3584.

Comment: This helped me get rid of empty `div`s.

Answer (score 12):

I will suggest move all templates to separate files, and don't do spagetti inside repeat

take a look here:

html:

```
<div ng-repeat = "data in comments">
    <div ng-include src="buildUrl(data.type)"></div>
 </div>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.comments = [
    {"_id":"52fb84fac6b93c152d8b4569",
       "post_id":"52fb84fac6b93c152d8b4567",
       "user_id":"52df9ab5c6b93c8e2a8b4567",
       "type":"hoot"},  
    {"_id":"52fb798cc6b93c74298b4568",
       "post_id":"52fb798cc6b93c74298b4567",
       "user_id":"52df9ab5c6b93c8e2a8b4567",
       "type":"story"},        
    {"_id":"52fb7977c6b93c5c2c8b456b",
       "post_id":"52fb7977c6b93c5c2c8b456a",
       "user_id":"52df9ab5c6b93c8e2a8b4567",
       "type":"article"}
  ];

  $scope.buildUrl = function(type) {
    return type + '.html';
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/HxnirSvMHNQ748M2WeRt?p=preview

Comment: This seems to be nice. I am building this with backend Laravel. I am just exploring Angularjs. Is this would be possible with laravel blade templating? if you have tried it with frameworks?

Comment: unfortunatelly, I'm not familiar with laravel. but,anyway, as long as it's angular code, angular will handle it in a sweet way for sure

Comment: Alright thanks for help. , definitely i would give a try to this method

Comment: @EugeneP Will angular build the template in the <ng-include /> once and then use it for the ng-repeat? Or will it fetch the new template from ng-include each time?

Comment: @EugeneP I'm going to answer my own question (^) above for anyone else: ng-include's are cached by the browser so an ng-include inside an ng-repeat would be cached