# Unable to use ng-if with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I was tried to use ng-if inside ng-repeat but it seems ng-if is not working properly.

I referred couple of forum links in StackOverflow but it doesn't help me.

I'm using angular version 1.3.0

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myModule">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <script src="/js/lib/angular-1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/lib/controllers/ifRepeatController.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

     <div ng-repeat = "data in comments">
      <div ng-if="data.type == 'hootsslllll' ">
          //differnt template with hoot data
       </div>
      <div ng-if="data.type == 'story' ">
          //differnt template with story data
       </div>
       <div ng-if="data.type == 'article' ">
          //differnt template with article data
       </div> 
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
var myIfRepeat = angular.module('myIfRepeat',[]);


myIfRepeat.controller('IfRepeatController', function ($scope,$http) {

     $scope.comments = [
            {"_id":"1",
               "post_id":"1",
               "user_id":"UserId1",
               "type":"hoot"},  
            {"_id":"2",
               "post_id":"2",
               "user_id":"UserId2",
               "type":"story"},        
            {"_id":"3",
               "post_id":"3",
               "user_id":"UserId3",
               "type":"article"}
          ];

});
```

As per the first condition, the first line should not get displayed (Below find the screenshot for more reference), however the line is getting displayed.

the reference link : [Using ng-if inside ng-repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751676/using-ng-if-inside-ng-repeat)

[image: Ng-If]

Now i added the controller in the div as advised, however i'm facing the same issue

Below i have given the screenshot for reference. Kindly help me how to solve this issue and please let me know in case of further clarifications.

[image: New screenshot with controller]

**Below provided screenshot on the working model used angular 1.3 version. If we use angular 1.0.2 the nf-if will not work properly (below provided the screenshot)**

[image: Working model screenshot]

**Screen shot for angular version 1.0.2**

[image]

Comment: Take care: `ngIf` creates its proper scope. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/kPRzdcrIzNw/cNaJdguCNeYJ

Comment: @Mik378 Sorry not able to understand clearly

Comment: Did you try with `ng-show` instead of `ngIf`?

Comment: @Mik378 No I have not tried with ng-show but how to use ng-if in this case.

Comment: If it works with `ng-show`, your issue surely provides from the particularity of `ng-if`, that doesn't share the current scope but extends it. If it does not work with `ng-show`, then your context is the cause. @j.wittwer points out a very potential cause (context cause ;))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not having issues with this working. Tweaked your code to fit into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vfDg/)

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="IfRepeatController">
    <div ng-repeat="data in comments">
        <div ng-if="data.type == 'hootsslllll' ">type={{data.type}}//differnt template with hoot data</div>
        <div ng-if="data.type == 'story' ">type={{data.type}}//differnt template with story data</div>
        <div ng-if="data.type == 'article' ">type={{data.type}}//differnt template with article data</div>
    </div>
</div>

function IfRepeatController($scope) {
    $scope.comments = [{
        "_id": "1",
            "post_id": "1",
            "user_id": "UserId1",
            "type": "hoot"
    }, {
        "_id": "2",
            "post_id": "2",
            "user_id": "UserId2",
            "type": "story"
    }, {
        "_id": "3",
            "post_id": "3",
            "user_id": "UserId3",
            "type": "article"
    }];
}
```

**Note:** reference angular 1.3.0 here: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.7/angular.min.js

Comment: sorry i don't understand how it works for you. In my earlier post of the code I missed the controller after that i added the controller and i tried it, however i'm facing the same issue.  Attached the screenshot for reference. kindly let me know for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `ng-controller`:

```
<body ng-controller="IfRepeatController">
```

Comment: as advised i added the controller but still i'm facing the same issue. In the above post i have attached the screenshot for more reference.

Comment: sorry i added the wrong module name it works fine attached the screenshot for reference

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. I cannot get ng-if to work correctly. The only way to get it to work is to evaluate the ng-if to the not operator (ng-if="!variableValue").  Is this an AngularJS version issue?

Answer (score 0):

This in not *AngularJs* Version issue, If `variableValue` has boolean it will work fine.

Sample code like this:

```
$scope.variableValue = true; in Controller

"<"div ng-if="!variableValue" ">"Don't show content"<"/div">"// This DIV doesn't show the content 
"<"div ng-if="variableValue" ">"show content"<"/div">"  // This DIV will show the content
```