# How to use ng-if with table to display td based on the condition

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

With reference to the earlier post on ng-if within DIV **for reference the link given here :: [Ng-If within DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413718/unable-to-use-ng-if-with-ng-repeat)** , however when i tried the same with ng-if inside table with ng-repeat on td it doesn't seems to work well. Correct me if I'm wrong I made 2 tries to display the column based on the condition but none works. Below i have given the code for reference. Could somebody help me on this. Kindly let know if you need more clarification.

**HTML**

***Try :: 1***

```
   <table>
        <tr ng-repeat = "data in comments">
            <td ng-if="data.type == 'hootsslllll' ">
             //differnt template with hoot data
            </td>
            <td ng-if="data.type == 'story' ">
             //differnt template with story data
            </td>
            <td ng-if="data.type == 'article' ">
            //differnt template with article data
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

***Try :: 2***

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat = "data in comments">
        <div ng-if="data.type == 'hootsslllll' ">
            <td> //differnt template with hoot data </td>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="data.type == 'story' ">
            <td> //differnt template with story data </td>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="data.type == 'article' ">
            <td> //differnt template with article data </td>
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `it doesn't seems to work well.` can you elaborate? What does it (not) do?

Comment: Tables sometimes don't like divs inside trs. Try removing the divs, and putting the ng-if expression straight into the td tag.

Comment: @ZackArgyle in my first try i did the same but it doesn't work

Comment: @: Tim Castelijns need to display the column based on the condtion

Comment: `ngIf` adds and removes dom nodes based on the condition, you might want to try `ngShow` or `ngHide` instead which simply sets the element in question to `display: none`.

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/pBcnmkQkEoVCTArYG0q2?p=preview. You'll have to tell us more about your code, angular version, etc. Try to come up with a minimal plunkr reproducing the problem. And tell us precisely what happens.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ng-if` should work for your **try::1**. Here is the fiddle working example

http://jsfiddle.net/shivaraj/n3xWB/

Answer (score 5):

Most of the browsers will ignore any other DOM elements within a table structure if it is not well formed. Which implies, in your above code you cannot have `div` tag within a `tr`. Try this instead

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat = "data in comments">
    <td ng-if="data.type == 'hootsslllll' "> //differnt template with hoot data </td>
    <td ng-if="data.type == 'story' "> //differnt template with story data </td>
    <td ng-if="data.type == 'article' "> //differnt template with article data </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Avoid using  inside  to adhere to better browser semantics. Moreover, when checking for equality '===' may be a better option, if you want to ensure the type of the value on the RHS of the equality expression.

This works for both `<table>` and `<div>` individually

```
<div ng-controller="tableCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="data in comments">
            <div ng-if="data.type === 'hootsslllll' ">//differnt template with hoot data</div>
            <div ng-if="data.type === 'story' ">//differnt template with story data</div>
            <div ng-if="data.type === 'article' ">//differnt template with article data</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mu6T6/3/