# Angularjs give classes based on variable value

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have the following php expression.

```
$isActive = ($value['is_active'] == 1) ? '<i class="btn fa fa-toggle-on 
isActive"></i>' : '<i class="btn fa fa-toggle-off isInactive"></i>';
```

How can i translate that into angularjs if statement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please show it.

Comment: `'<i class="btn fa fa-toggle-on" ng-class="{isActive: is_active}"></i>'` where `is_active` is a scope variable

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bgnjzwjm/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're asking for [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).
you need to set a variable to represent 'is_active', and use it in your html like so:

```
<i class="btn fa" ng-class="{'fa-toggle-on isActive' : is_active, 
                             'fa-toggle-off isInactive' : !is_active}"></i>
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for your time and answers.
I found the following and get my work done.
[Using ng-if inside ng-repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751676/using-ng-if-inside-ng-repeat)

So my code now looks like this

```
<td ng-if="client.clientStatus == 0"><i class="btn fa fa-toggle-off isInactive"></i></td>
<td ng-if="client.clientStatus == 1"><i class="btn fa fa-toggle-on isActive"></i></td>
```