# ng-repeat show content depending on data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have the following object:

```
{
    "items": [
        { "type": "groupA", "name": "title 1" },
        { "type": "groupB", "name": "title 2"}
    ]
}
```

I have the following `ng-repeat` going on below:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data.items">
    {{ item.name }}
</div>
```

Ideally, I'd love to be able to show how I display `item.name` depending on the **type**.

So for example, if the **type** is equal to *groupA* i'd like to have:

```
<input value="{{ item.name }}" />
```

And if the **type** is equal to *groupB*, i'd like to have:

```
<div>{{ item.name }}</div>
```

Is this possible? Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could accomplish his? I'm new to angular so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751676/using-ng-if-inside-ng-repeat, it is basically a duplicate of what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is angular conditionals known as ngIf:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data.items">
    <div ng-if="item.type == 'groupA'">
        <input value="{{ item.name }}" />
    </div>
    <div ng-if="item.type == 'groupB'">
        <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

More on Angular ngIf function here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

A second way is showing the appropriate element based on the value of item.type, using ngShow:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data.items">
    <input ng-show="item.type == 'groupA'" value="{{ item.name }}" />
    <div ng-show="item.type == 'groupB'" />{{ item.name }}</div>
</div>
```

More on ngShow here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

And a third way is switches. Although switches might be a lot of clutter for showing one of only two types of element types. More on switches here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

EDIT: A little more clarification added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-if directive within ng-repeat. Try this:-

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in data.items">
    <input ng-if="item.type == 'groupA'" value="{{ item.name }}" />
    <div ng-if="item.type == 'groupB'">
       {{ item.name }}
    </div> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf). For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data.items">
    <div ng-if="item.type == 'groupA'">
        <input value="{{ item.name }}" />
    </div>      
    <div ng-if="item.type == 'groupB'">
        {{ item.name }}
    </div>    
</div>
```