# ng-repeat how to make a specific button not repeat

Tags: angularjs

Right now my button is repeating because I am using `ng-repeat` to repeat the 2 versions buttons in my page, how can make just this button not repeat? that button needs to be together with the other ones, I know I can put this button out and will not repeat, but I need hide this button and make just appear when version buttons appear too.

everything is fine, just that button is repeating, is someway to use ng-repeat="none" or something similar?

Thanks.

**html**:

```
<div>
    <div class="item"
      ng-repeat="version in versions"
      ng-class="{active: version.isActive}"
      ng-class="{active: }">
      <a ng-click="setDiffed(version)"
        ng-class="{active: version.isDiffActive}"
        name="compare-type"><i></i>
      </a>
      <h4 ng-click="setMaster(version)">{{ version.label }}</h4>
    </div>
    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary">
      back to home
    </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: inside `ngRepeat` you can check `$first`, `$last`, `$index` - So you can add on the button `ng-if="$first"` so it will be available only on the first repeated element

Comment: use `ng-if` like seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21751828/804928)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this button out and show it only if there are any versions.

Simplified HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="version in versions">
  <button>
    {{version}}
  </button>
</div>
<button ng-show="versions.length > 0">
  back to home
</button>
```

See how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/qd4j6964/

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ng-show` or `ng-if`, somthing like:

```
<div>
    <div class="item"
      ng-repeat="version in versions"
      ng-class="{active: version.isActive}"
      ng-class="{active: }">
      <a ng-show = "Your condition for showing or not" ng-click="setDiffed(version)"
        ng-class="{active: version.isDiffActive}"
        name="compare-type"><i></i>
      </a>
      <h4 ng-click="setMaster(version)">{{ version.label }}</h4>
    </div>
    <button type="button" ng-show = "Your condition for showing or not" class="btn btn-primary">
      back to home
    </button>

  </div>
```

AngularJS Documentation  - [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) .

Comment: thanks, but i just wanna hide this: <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary">
      back to home
    </button>

Comment: I can see Your condition for showing or not, I am sorry but I not understand how to do this :(